# About algebraic variety and formal power series

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let $K$ be a field and consider the polynomial ring $K[x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_n]$ in $n$ variables. Consider the ideal $(f_1,f_2, \cdots, f_n)$, then the set $$V(f_1,f_2,\cdots, d_n)=\{x \in K^n| f_1(x)=\cdots=f_n(x)=0 \} \subset K^n$$ defines a **variety** of the polynomials $f_i, \ i=1(1)n$, where $x=(x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_n)$.

My question-

What happened to the case $K[[x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_n]]$ of formal power series ie.,e when each $f_1, f_2,\cdots , f_n$ are formal power series ?

Do we still call the new set  a **variety** ?

Comment: How do you substitute an element of $K^n$ into a formal power series?

Comment: @AnginaSeng, did you think anymore about the question ? We can replace $K^n$ by $\mathfrak{m}^n$, where $\mathfrak{m}$ is maximal ideal in $K$. But can we extend anymore ?